# Returning result from activity via Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two classes in my project: main and importer. Main starts Importer with startActivityForResult(), but how can Importer return its status to Main? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When `Importer` finishes its job, it has to call [`setResult(int, Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) and the `finish()`. Main will receive the result in [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29). I am assuming that both `Importer` and `Main` extend `Activity`.

Overrid this method inside `Main`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

inside `importer`

```
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("result", "i am the result");
    setResult(1000, data);
    finish();
```

then

`onActivityResult` will receive  `resultCode = 1000`  and `data != null`

Comment: "I am assuming that both importer and Main are Activity" yes, they are. Thanks, but can you tell me how to use those voids?

Answer (score 0):

By calling [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) in `Importer` when you are ready to return to `MainActivity`. You can use `setResult(int)` to just send back a result code or `setresult(int, Intent)` to send back data.

Then use `onActivityResult()` in `MainAcitivty` to do what you need with the data

The [Activity Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) have an example of doing this, although I don't believe it shows using `setResult()` but its pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

start Activity2 as `startActivityForResult(Activity2,REQUEST_CODE)`

after you finished your task in the next `Activity2`

```
Intent output = new Intent();
output.putExtra("value1", somedata);
setResult(RESULT_OK, output);
finish();
```

and use onActivityResult() in Activity1

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
     val1 = data.getIntExtra("value1");
}
```